# How can I ensure the writable flag is true before send()?

Tags: websocket, dart, dart-async

I am creating an abstraction layer for Dart WebSocket who is also protocol compatible with Socket.IO, but it has a problem I can not solve.

The follow code convert the HttpRequest into a WebSocket and save the socket instance on the Transport... Here you can see I change the value of the `writable` flag to true in order to inform the socket is open.

```
WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(req).then((socket) {
  this._socket = socket;
  this.writable = true;

  this._socket.handleError(() {
    this.onClose();
  });

  // start listen the socket;
  socket.listen((packet) {
    this.onData(packet);
  });
}).catchError((Exception e) {
  this.onError('Can\'t conenct with the socket.', e.toString());
});
```

(The full code can be founded [here](https://github.com/Designture/Connexa/blob/master/lib/src/transports/WebSocket.dart).)

When I debug the code first the debugger stops inside that closure and only then stops here, where the check is make but `writable` still false :/

```
void flush([_]) {
  if (this._readyState != SocketStates.closed && this.transport.writable &&
      !this._writeBuffer.isEmpty) {
```

(The full code can be founded [here](https://github.com/Designture/Connexa/blob/master/lib/src/Socket.dart))
I really need help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor makes an async call but doesn't return a future (not possible in a constructor)

```
WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(req).then
```

Use a static method instead which returns `Future<WebSocketTransformer>` or use an `init` method where you initiaize your class after creation. 
There might be other problems but yor code does not  show how you use your class therefore its hard to tell.

Comment: Oh... Sorry... A delete by mistake the link with all usage code :/
I Update the post :)

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion already? Does the problem still persist. Your example is too complex. I can't know from looking at the source what returns a future and what returns a value. You need to create a minimal example that allows to reproduce the problem and add it to you question.

Comment: No... I'm from Portugal soo I woke up now... :D OK... I will try your sugestion... Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: I create a new emitter after the upgrade request who informs the opening of the Transport (`this.emit('open, this);`)... On the Server class I just start the Socket when I receive the `open event` (`this.once('open', (_) {// start the Socket});`)

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with this comment. You accepted my answer therefore I assume your problem is fixed now.

Comment: Yes... Thanks for the ideia :D